# Best way to store products of Multiple Fields of different information

Tags: sql-server, database-design, c#

I have around 6 table in one of 3rd party cloud database. I am planning to Build it MSSQL. My problem in each of these table there are 20-40 field of different information and Item. Which approach better to manage my data having a separate table for each or in a single table. if i store all in single table the number of field will in a table will be very large. I also plan to use C# for the Front end to develop Product Management System.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have 6 entity types with different attributes then they should be stored in 6 different tables.

If they have attributes that are largely overlapping then you might consider storing multiple different types of entities in the same table.